# How to attach debugger to iOS app after launch?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have an issue I am troubleshooting which occurs very infrequently and doesn't seem to happen when I have things running under Xcode.

Is it possible to run an app normally (i.e. from Springboard) until my issue occurs, and then attach a debugger at that point?

I would prefer to do this without jailbreaking if possible.

Comment: **See also [How to debug an iOS extension (.appex)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524051/how-to-debug-an-ios-extension-appex) (for a more complete answer)**

Comment: **And: [Xcode's Profiler does not show Symbol names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967070/8740349) fix** (which can be caused by Attach approach)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

- Attach your device connected your Mac
- *Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name*
- In the dialog sheet, enter the name of your App as it appears in the `Debug navigator` when started via Xcode (e.g. Target's name not bundle-id).

If the app is already running, the debugger will attach to the running process. If it isn't running, it will wait for the app to launch and then attach.

Comment: Ole, thanks for the answer.  I was looking for a way to do this.  When I go to attach the debugger, it looks like it attaches but then I get this message: warning: Unable to read symbols for /var/mobile/Applications/ {GUID}/{APPNAME}.app/{APPNAME} (file not found).  When I press the "stop" button in XCode, the app terminates.  Looks like it's not finding the debug symbols, though it is being built in debug mode.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have a problem with the **If it isn't running, it will wait for the app to launch and then attach.** part. It doesn't work. I use the process name to wait for the app to call. I launch the app on the iPhone, but the debugger never realizes the app has started.

Comment: @BrianV -- you need to make sure you're compiling with -ggdb if you want to be able to attach to the process.

Comment: I agree with Jonny; my experience is that the attach works on the simulator, but won't attach to the actual device.

Comment: @JamesMoore: Attach worked for me on device just now, no problem.

Comment: NOTE: In Xcode 5.0.1+ it is `Debug > Attach to Process > By Process Identifier (PID) or Name` http://stackoverflow.com/a/20193088/175830

Comment: Looks like they went back to "Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name..." in Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 128):

I'll leave this here since neither of the other 2 answers gave me quite enough detail without a little bit of a struggle.

1. Run your app in the simulator and take note of the name in the Debug navigator 
   [image]
2. Plug in your device and don't forget to select your device as the target
   [image]
3. Debug > Attach to Process > By Process Identifier (PID) or Name
   [image]
4. Enter the name from step 1 and attach. That should be all you have to do.
   [image]

Comment: You should have 1000 upvotes. Debugging things that start via a cutom url scheme can be a pain in the ass without this neat trick. Many thanks!

Comment: I wish I saw this answer before I spent 20 minutes figuring this out on my own :(

Comment: This works in that it attaches to the process, but I can't seen to get any log output which is what I really need. Any ideas?

Comment: @Orlando - If you're looking for log output, I highly recommend DeviceConsole: https://github.com/rpetrich/deviceconsole

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. and I get error: `Could not attach to PID` I tried both the name and its ID. I tried while the app is running and while it's stopped..

Comment: Same issue as @Orlando

Answer (score 49):

In Xcode 5.0.1 and 6 it's the menu bar items:

```
Debug > Attach to Process > By Process Identifier (PID) or Name...
```

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 7 it's just:

```
Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name...
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to debug the app by adding a breakpoint on the AppCoordinator file `init()` method on the `super.init()` line.

I was able to turn off the wifi/internet and then by pass the developer verification.