# How to debug a "second run" in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have a bug happening on the second run and onward of an application.
meaning I run it in Xcode, click stop, close the app, and open the app again.

The problem is, I can't use the Xcode debugging tools during this second run (as I opened the app directly from the phone, not Xcode).

How can I debug these situations? (besides NSLogs...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach debugger to IOS app after launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721830/attach-debugger-to-ios-app-after-launch)

Comment: I've always just run it again, from Xcode.

Comment: Do you *stop/shutdown* the app or background it? The debugger will definitely keep running if you background the app. . not sure what happens if you stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing a proper BOOL in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] to check for the second and onward runs like this:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@“NotFirstRun“]) {
   //this is the second or onward run 
} else {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@“NotFirstRun“]
   //this is the first run
}
```