# Application terminates when running in Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am seeing this message every time when I'm running my app in iPad .I'm getting issue in popup as Restore the connection to "iPad" and run "AppName" again, or if "AppName" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > AppName. and in console it is showing this issue Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

This issue was occurring each and every time while running in iPad.How to solve this?

Update: Actually I'm getting issue while presenting second view  GADInterstitial Ad is also presented,because of this Ad I'm getting this issue.If I remove this Ad code there is no issue .But in my view i need to get Ad.

Answer (score 0):

First Go to Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> Select Your Project and Delete Derived data.

Others Way, Just stop running and Run Again. This way is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Renish Dadhaniya .I already tried that thing but showing same issue .I'm going mad with this .I tried everything but showing same issue...someone help me

Comment: Which Xcode Versions you are using? This was very often with Xcode 6.0. But it is Fixed with Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: Actually after picking image from gallery/camera and presenting next view only I'm getting this popup issue..

Comment: Please review this link may be it's Helpful. My issue was fixed with Xcode 6.1.1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name      2-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721830/attach-debugger-to-ios-app-after-launch

Comment: These process didn't helped me @Renish Dadhaniya..actually what will be the problem if it shows this message

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits into your problem. But I had the problem that I had 2 significant problems that caused this:

1. I used RawMutablePointers, which I had to deinitialize and deallocate to release memory capacities. Otherwise the memory is crowded after some seconds (I used this for capturing camera feed). Taken memory was shown as >500mb.
2. I processed images. Camera feed was taken and converted to UIImage. To show this image I added those UIImages to subviews. By using the `.addSubView`it started to crowd my memory even if the used memory always has been below 50mb. Before I added a new sublayer I removed everything before by this:
   `self.grayScaledCameraView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })`

Doing both solved my crashing like you described.