# iOS app working on simulator but not over TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, testflight

i've got a problem with TestFlight.

My app works fine in iOS simulator (8.1 & 9.1) and on my iPad (9.0.2) when connected over USB cable.
Now i want to share my app over TestFlight with some friends.
After download and install via TestFlight the same app don't work on the same iPad it worked fine before.

When i start the TestFlight version it takes some seconds then the screen turns black and after a few more seconds i get back to the home screen.
After connecting the iPad again there are no crash logs on device.

What can i do to find the error? Is there a possibility to debug TestFlight apps with the debug console from xcode?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using the simulator and attached with the USB are you using the release scheme?

If not, in Xcode:

1. Product
2. Edit Scheme
3. Select Run on left panel
4. In the right panel select Info at the top and then Release (instead of Debug) for Build Configuration

Then, when you build in the simulator or on your (connected) iPad you will, most likely, get the same result as the TF install (or a deployment) and can find where your app is crashing. Don't forget to turn on All Exceptions in the Breakpoint Navigator.

I've done this and it works.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip, after changing i got a code signing error. 
With this solved everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a crash due to TF analytics, but I might be wrong. Try debugging your downloaded version by attaching the debugger to it. Here's how to do that: [Attach debugger to IOS app after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721830/attach-debugger-to-ios-app-after-launch)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't debug a downloaded app in console mode from xCode. Try a a tool like Crashlytics: create an account (it's free), and you'll get the crash log.