# IOS Development: Background BLE with CBPeripheral periodically updating subscribed characteristic

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth, updating

I'm currently trying to develop a Bluetooth IOS application that can work in background. 
I methodically followed the tuts on the IOS developper website, and it works pretty fine; I'm getting stuck whenever I want to update a subscribed characteristic in background.

When my Peripheral device enters in background, I want the characteristic to periodically update, so that it send a notification to the Central device, taking advantage of the characteristic subscription mode. 
*Note : for now the characteristic is only a timestamp, updated every 5 seconds, in order to test if it works well*

First I implemented a `NSTimer`, but as expected it is killed when the Peripheral app enters in background. Then I tried to establish a **Background Fetch mode**, but it is only possible to set a minimum refresh interval (and not warming up my application on fixed period).

Does somebody have an idea on how to proceed/overcome the problem?

Thank you!

*Ps: I appologize for my English, I'm a bit rusty*

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by subscribing to the characteristic and implementing bluetooth backgrounding and state restoration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33137848/22147

Comment: When I read the corresponding part on the apple developper website, I understood that State restoration is only helpfull to wake up a Peripheral after a long inactivity period. 
In this case I want to periodically update the Peripheral characteristic withoud any loss of signal between the two devices. 
Maybe I could call  the update function in another background mode? Such as Background location update ? For instance when the user moves, it update the timestamp characteristic, which is automatically sent to the Central ?