# How can I see console.log in xcode for a release build for React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I would like to see some console.log in a release build for a React Native iOS project. I have searched around but haven't found anything and I'm not familiar with xcode. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9721830/5832644

Answer (score 0):

You can use the device console, you get from Xcode -> Devices and Simulators - > Select your device -> open console