# How to debug Network Extension

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, networkextension

I read did everything as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24288906) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722089), but my breakpoints are still don't work (NSLog and os_log don't work either).

This is what I see in the console after `self.providerManager?.connection.startVPNTunnel()`
*Last disconnect error for MyAppConfig changed from "The VPN session failed because an internal error occurred." to "none"
Last disconnect error for MyAppConfig changed from "none" to "The VPN session failed because an internal error occurred."*

I tried to monitor the event of changes in the VPN status (NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange) and this is what I saw:
*VPN Status changed:
Connecting...
VPN Status changed:
Disconnected...*

I can't even figure out if a method 
`func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)` works in my class PacketTunnelProvider or not.

One more detail, I do not see my network extension in the list of available extensions (for example, in Instruments).

What else can i try to do for debugging, and how i can understand does my extension work or not?