# Is it possible to debugging an iOS app that's running on device without re-building/deploying the code?

Tags: swift, xcode, remote-debugging

Challenge: I'm testing my iOS app on the device and the app works well for some time and I'm not able to catch any issues. I disconnect the device from my machine and keep using it for days with no issues. Then out of the blue, as soon as I launch the App on the phone, it immediately closes (crashes). When I connect the device to the computer so that I can see what's going on, I cannot replicate the crash because the app gets redeployed and it resolves the issue. So I'm unable to find the root cause of the issue.
Any suggestion is really appreciated!

Comment: Free developer account allows you to store your app in an iPhone for a certain amount of days (not sure about exact count). This may be the problem you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The debug Provisioning Profiles are expire after 7 days in free Apple Developer accounts. This is why your application after a certain period of time just won't launch.

As of to how to debug an already running application, you can follow the steps that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9722089/6791677) answer provides.

> Debug > Attach to Process by PID or Name

or find you running app in the list of processes using
`Debug > Attach to Process`

[image]